# db2 recursive multiple update on result

Tags: db2, sql-update, recursive-query

I would like to perform various updates on the result set returned by a recursive query without having to rewrite the recursive query for each update?

Is there a way to delimit every UPDATE from each other?

Here is my code:

```
WITH IDS (Level, $COID, $COID_REF, $CONAME) AS
  (SELECT 0, x.$COID, x.$COID_REF, x.$CONAME
    FROM MCINT.$EXT x
    WHERE $COID = X'1234567890123456'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B.Level + 1, c.$COID, c.$COID_REF, c.$CONAME
    FROM IDS B, MCINT.$EXT C
    WHERE B.$COID_REF = C.$COID AND B.Level < 30)

-- perform first update on ther result set
SELECT COUNT(*) AS updated_rows
  FROM  FINAL TABLE
    (UPDATE MCINT.$EXT_LF 
        SET $CUR_ACC_MET_DATA = REPLACE($CUR_ACC_MET_DATA, 'p_mcint', 't_mcint')
     WHERE $COID IN (SELECT $COID_REF FROM IDS));

-- second recursive scan
WITH IDS (Level, $COID, $COID_REF, $CONAME) AS
  (SELECT 0, x.$COID, x.$COID_REF, x.$CONAME
    FROM MCINT.$EXT x
    WHERE $COID = X'1234567890123456'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B.Level + 1, c.$COID, c.$COID_REF, c.$CONAME
    FROM IDS B, MCINT.$EXT C
    WHERE B.$COID_REF = C.$COID AND B.Level < 30)

-- perform second update on the result set
SELECT COUNT(*) AS updated_rows
  FROM  FINAL TABLE
    (UPDATE MCINT.$EXT_LF 
        SET $CUR_ACC_MET_DATA = REPLACE($CUR_ACC_MET_DATA, 'p_xcdata', 't_xcdata')
     WHERE $COID IN (SELECT $COID_REF FROM IDS));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I missed something, the two statements differ only in this:

```
SET $CUR_ACC_MET_DATA = REPLACE($CUR_ACC_MET_DATA, 'p_mcint', 't_mcint')
```

vs.

```
SET $CUR_ACC_MET_DATA = REPLACE($CUR_ACC_MET_DATA, 'p_xcdata', 't_xcdata')
```

If that's the case, you can probably do it with a single update:

```
SET $CUR_ACC_MET_DATA = REPLACE(REPLACE($CUR_ACC_MET_DATA, 'p_mcint', 't_mcint'),
                                'p_xcdata', 't_xcdata')
```

Comment: cool, thanks, I didn't know I could do it like that. Not a db expert even less db2 expert.
cheers